# `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` combined with `JOIN`

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, limit

I have an sql sentence like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, films.category AS filmCategory FROM films LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.unique = films.ref ORDER BY unique ASC LIMIT 0, 4";
```

that doesn't work. It works without the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` parts, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, films.category AS filmCategory FROM films LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.unique = films.ref";
```

I can't seem to find the way to add `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to get only the first 4 items from the `films` table. The joined part is only supposed to get some further information from another table for these four items afterwards. How is it done in the right way?

Comment: The LIMIT clause applies to the entire query, not just the `films` table. If you want to limit just that table, you have to use a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to limit a specific table, you have to use a subquery.

```
SELECT *, films.category AS filmCategory
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM films
      ORDER BY ref ASC
      LIMIT 4) films
LEFT OUTER JOIN items
ON items.`unique` = films.ref
ORDER BY `unique` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't make this work though. Why is `films` written once more after the parenthesis?

Comment: @Steeven . . . That is an alias for the subquery.  It uses the same name as the table so the references in the rest of the query don't have to change.

Comment: I can make your code work if I remove the last sentence `ORDER BY 'unique' ASC`. It is strange that it doesn't work with this line; both the tables `films` and `items` has the `unique` coloumn.

Comment: It seems to work, if I change the last sentence to `ORDER BY films.'unique' ASC`. It needs the table identifier here also apparently. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Of course, if a column appears in multiple tables, you have to disambiguate it. Since you didn't post your schema, I couldn't have known that such an unusual column name would be repeated (now I suspect you're using `unique` for the column most would call `id`).